# Increase element size everytime window is resized

Tags: javascript, function, loops

my problem today is that I have 12 elements with size 60px x 60px and I'd like to increase the size with 0.2 everytime the screen size increase of 10px, with javascript. For example: screensize 600px and element size 60.2 x 60.2, screensize 610px and element size 60.4 x 60.4 and so on. It would give something like this to increase :

```
var circle_data={
        container: document.querySelector(".container"),
        classname: "astro-item",
        nb_elem: 12,
        elem_size: 60,
    };
    var screenSize = window.innerWidth;
    circle_data.elem_size += 0.2;
```

The thing is that I don't know how to increase everytime the screen size increase by 10px

Thanks for your help !!

So with your answers here's the code I tried but it doesn't work, maybe because I already have a function that set elements size up, here's the full script:

```
function circle_container(objdata) {
            var circle_dim=objdata.container.getBoundingClientRect();
            var rayon=Math.round(circle_dim.width/2 - objdata.elem_size/2);
            var center_x=rayon;
            var center_y=rayon;

            if (objdata.rayon) rayon*=objdata.rayon/100;

            for(var i=0;i<objdata.nb_elem;i++) {
                var new_elem=objdata.container.querySelector("."+objdata.classname+i);
                if (!new_elem) {
                    var new_elem=document.createElement("button");
                    new_elem.className="astro-item"+" "+objdata.classname+i;
                    var new_img=document.createElement("img");
                    new_img.src = astroList[i].icon;
                }

                new_elem.style.position="absolute";
                new_elem.style.width=objdata.elem_size+"px";
                new_elem.style.height=objdata.elem_size+"px";

                new_elem.style.top=Math.round( (center_y - rayon * Math.cos(i*(2*Math.PI)/objdata.nb_elem)))+"px";
                new_elem.style.left=Math.round( (center_x + rayon * Math.sin(i*(2*Math.PI)/objdata.nb_elem)))+"px";

                objdata.container.appendChild(new_elem);
                new_elem.appendChild(new_img);
            }
        }

        var circle_data={
            container: document.querySelector(".container"),
            classname: "astro-item",
            nb_elem: 12,
            elem_size: 60,
        };
        function onResize(e) {
            var screenSize = e.target.outerWidth;       
            var width = (screenSize - (screenSize %  100) + (((screenSize + 10) %  100)/10 *2))/10;
            var items = document.querySelectorAll('.astro-item');
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].innerHTML  = 'width: ' + screenSize + ' size: ' + width ;
            }

        }       
        circle_container(circle_data);
        addEvent(window,"resize",function() { 
            circle_container(circle_data); 
            onresize(); 
        });
```

The purpose of this function is to create 12 buttons aligned in circle (just like a wheel) and fully responsive, that's why I need them to get bigger when the screen gets larger. Thank you so much !

Comment: are you willing to use Jquery?

Comment: Simple CSS and percentage based sizes?

Comment: I'm using pure JS, no framework thx !

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript bind an event **onresize** and set size based on window width.  The size increase 0.2 everytime the screen size increase of 10px:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);

var onresize = function(e) {

       var width = e.target.outerWidth;       
       circle_data.elem_size = (width - (width %  100) + (((width + 10) %  
      100)/10 *2))/10;
}
```

**Working example:**

**(open in full screen)**

***Edited for max min limitations**

```js
 var min = 500; //min width in pixel
var max= 700;  //max width in pixel

window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);

var onresize = function(e) {

       var width = e.target.outerWidth;       
       var s = (width - (width %  100) + (((width + 10) %  100)/10 *2))/10

     if(width <=max && width >=min){
        //change size here
         document.getElementById('s').innerHTML  = 'width: ' + width + ' size: ' + s ;
    }
   


}
```

```html
<span id='s'> </span>
```

Comment: It works ! I just need to define min and max size for the elements but eveything I try doesn't work ! I tried conditions, loops and I can define min size but not max